How can use SQL to combine multiple rows into one row based off a unique value in a column?
enter image description here
I have only one table to work wit and don't want to create new tables.
For example in the screenshot: I want to combine rows based off a unique value in column A and turn it into the table on the right.
How can I write a SQL statement to do this?
I am using SQL in Snowflake.
Thanks!
I've tried researching online but can't find an example specific to my needs.

I tried to add a tag for "snowflake". Don't know for sure what product you mean, please verify and then correct/confirm.

Welcome to SO.  Please don't use images or link to them in your posts

It's a "pivot. Thousands of examples.

A Case Pivot will give you these results
with t(accountid, questionid, status) as (
    select * from values
    (1,'a','open'),
    (1,'b','closed'),
    (1,'c','in progress'),
    (2,'d','open'),
    (2,'e','closed'),
    (2,'f','in progress'),
    (3,'g','open'),
    (3,'h','closed'),
    (3,'i','in progress')
),
t1 as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by accountid order by questionid) - 1 as rn 
    from t
)
select 
    accountid,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 0 then questionid end) as questionid1,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 1 then questionid end) as questionid2,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 2 then questionid end) as questionid3,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 0 then status end) as status1,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 1 then status end) as status2,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 2 then status end) as status3
from t1
group by accountid, floor(rn / 3)
order by accountid, floor(rn / 3);




ACCOUNTID
QUESTIONID1
QUESTIONID2
QUESTIONID3
STATUS1
STATUS2
STATUS3




1
a
b
c
open
closed
in progress


2
d
e
f
open
closed
in progress


3
g
h
i
open
closed
in progress



